# Unique key in SQL Power Architect? Forward Engineering

Tags: postgresql

I want to know if there is a way to create unique keys (not PKs) in SQL Power Architect using forward engineering.

I've searched google, saw the tutorials by the software vendor, and checked out in youtube, but I didn't came across with a solution.

Can anybody here help me out?

What I want to do is to define an unique (or alternate) key (UK/AK) for some attributes in one row.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Power Architect 1.0.6 on a Mac and the following instructions work for me.

1. Highlight the table you want to add the constraint to
2. Click on the "New Index" button on the toolbar and the "Index Properties" dialog appears, with sections for the name and type of constraint and a list of columns.
3. Enter a name for your constraint
4. Tick the "Unique" button
5. Tick the check box next to each column over which you want to define the constraint
6. Finally, click the "OK" button to add the constraint.

Hope this helps.